# How to handle relationship between sale and product

Tags: erd

I want to manage sales, there was many to many relationship between sale and product, so i broke it by adding an entity sales description among them now the relationship among these three entities is as follows.

[image]

"Sales descrition" entity have composite primary key consisting upon customerId, customerName,date,time attribute which should go as foreign key in "Product" table. Now i am confused that whenever i will add product i will have to add customerId,customerName,date,time which does not seems logically true.

Any idea please that how should i handle relationship between sale and product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would organize this by storing customer data in a customers table.  Then the sale table uses the customerid from the customers table as a foreign key.  The sale table should have its own primary key.  That saleid key becomes a foreign key in the sales description table.  The product is linked by including the productid in the sales description table as a foreign key.  So your tables would look something like this:

Customer table
- customerid
- customer name
- customer address

Sale table
- saleid
- customerid (foreign key)
- datetime

Product table
- productid
- product name
- product price

Sale description table
- saleid (foreign key)
- productid (foreign key)
- quantity

Answer (score 0):

It should be the other way around. The product id should be a foreign key in the Sales Description table. The Sales Description is the relationship between Sale and a Product. The customer id belong in the Sale table and should probably be a foreign key to a customer table. This way a single customer may have many sales and each sale may have many products. I Assume here that Sale == Order.